# Java components does not appear when the window is centered

Tags: java, swing

I have a weird problem and I have no idea what causes this.
I have a dialog class which simply shows an error/warning message to the screen. Interestingly, when I set the window center, the components does not appear (unless I re-size it).

[image]

However, when I change the screen location, components appear on the JPanel just fine.

[image]

I basically change this line to `int x = (dim.width - w) / 3;`and it works. But it doesn't when the width divided by 2. So, the dialog works anywhere but center. Please, let me know what I am missing here.

I appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Here's the code:

---

An MCVE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UKDialog extends JDialog {

   private JButton button1;
   private JLabel message;

   public UKDialog(String message, String buttonText) {
       this.button1 = new JButton(buttonText);
       this.message = new JLabel(message);
       setWarning();
   }

   public void setWarning() {
       this.setModal(true);
       this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
       if (this.message.getText().length() <= 30) {
           this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(650, 300));
           this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(650, 300));
           this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(650, 300));
       } else if (this.message.getText().length() > 30) {
           this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(870, 300));
           this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(870, 300));
           this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(870, 300));
       }

       this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

       JPanel messagePanel = new JPanel();
       messagePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

       JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
       buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
       buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));

       this.message.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 40));

       this.button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(230, 80));
       this.button1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 45));
       this.button1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(139, 71, 137));
       this.button1.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
       this.button1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
               okActionPerformed(evt);
           }
       });

       messagePanel.add(this.message, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       buttonPanel.add(this.button1);
       this.add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
       // calculate the new location of the window
       Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
       int w = this.getSize().width;
       int h = this.getSize().height;
       int x = (dim.width - w) / 2;
       int y = (dim.height - h) / 5;
       this.setLocation(x, y);
       this.setVisible(true);
   }

   protected void okActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      UKDialog.this.dispose();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main GUI");
            JButton button = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Push Me") {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  String message = "Message is Long Enough???";
                  String buttonText = "Button";
                  UKDialog ukDialog = new UKDialog(message, buttonText);
               }
            });

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
            panel.add(button);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(panel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }
      });    
   }
}
```

This is my class calls the warning class with the main method.

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JDialog;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout;
    import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class PAndDeliveryNotification extends JDialog {

    private JButton button1;
    private JLabel messageTitle;
    private JTextField text;
    private boolean reply;
    private String typedText;
    private ArrayList<String[]> remainingInvoices;
    private String stopNum = null;
    private String currentStopNum, lastStopNum;

    public PAndDeliveryNotification(ArrayList<String[]> rInvoices, String buttonText1) {
        this.button1 = new JButton(buttonText1);
        this.remainingInvoices = rInvoices;
    }

    public void setDelivStopNo() throws IOException {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("images/uk.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        this.setIconImage(image);

        //frame properties
        this.setModal(true);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //frame size
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 600));
        this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(900, 600));
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(900, 600));

        JPanel upperPanel = new JPanel(new WrapLayout());
        upperPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        for (int i = 0; i < this.remainingInvoices.size(); i++) {
            String[] invoice;
            invoice = (String[]) this.remainingInvoices.get(i);
            if (i == 0) {
                this.currentStopNum = invoice[0];
            }
            if (i == this.remainingInvoices.size() - 1) {
                this.lastStopNum = invoice[0];
            }
            StopItem item = new StopItem(invoice);
            item.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(770, 120));
            upperPanel.add(item);
        }
        upperPanel.repaint();
        upperPanel.revalidate();
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(upperPanel);
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(770, 600));
        pane.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 0));
        pane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
        this.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        lowerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        lowerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));

        JPanel messagePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        messagePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 80));
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240, 80));

        this.messageTitle = new JLabel("Enter Delivery Stop Number:");
        this.messageTitle.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 40));
        this.messageTitle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(480, 80));
        this.text = new JTextField(3);
        this.text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 80));
        this.text.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 40));
        this.text.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        this.text.requestFocus();
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c tabtip.exe");

        this.button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(230, 80));
        this.button1.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 45));
        this.button1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(139, 71, 137));
        this.button1.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
        this.button1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                saveStopNumActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        messagePanel.add(this.messageTitle);
        messagePanel.add(this.text);
        buttonPanel.add(this.button1);
        lowerPanel.add(messagePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        lowerPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(lowerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        // calculate the new location of the window
        int w = this.getSize().width;
        int h = this.getSize().height;

        int x = (dim.width - w) / 2;
        int y = 0;

        this.setLocation(x, y);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void saveStopNumActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        this.stopNum = this.text.getText();
        try {
            if (stopNum == null) {
                new UKDialog("Fields cannot be empty!", "OK");
                return;
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(stopNum) < Integer.parseInt(this.currentStopNum)) {
                new UKDialog("Delivery cannot be before pick up!", "OK");
                return;
            } else if (Integer.parseInt(stopNum) > Integer.parseInt(this.lastStopNum) + 1) {
                new UKDialog("Enter stop number between " + this.currentStopNum + 1 + " and "
                        + this.lastStopNum, "OK");
                return;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            new UKDialog("Please enter numeric values!", "OK");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println(this.stopNum);
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.dispose();
    }

    public String getStopNum() {
        return this.stopNum;
    }

    private class StopItem extends JPanel {

        private JPanel numPanel = new JPanel();
        private JLabel itemNumber = new JLabel();
        private JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        private JLabel invNoLbl = new JLabel();
        private JLabel consigneeLbl = new JLabel();
        private JLabel locationLbl = new JLabel();
        private final String pUStopNo;
        private final String invoiceNo;
        private final String consignee;
        private final String location;

        public StopItem(String[] invoice) {
            this.pUStopNo = invoice[0];
            this.invoiceNo = invoice[1];
            this.consignee = invoice[2];
            this.location = invoice[3];
            //Left and numberpanels
            this.numPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.numPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
            this.leftPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 90));
            //number panel
            this.itemNumber.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 45));
            this.itemNumber.setText(String.valueOf("  " + pUStopNo));
            //this.numPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
            this.numPanel.add(this.itemNumber);
            //Main panel
            this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2));
            this.invNoLbl.setText("Invoice #: " + this.invoiceNo);
            this.invNoLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 35));
            this.consigneeLbl.setText("Consignee: " + this.consignee);
            this.consigneeLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 35));
            this.locationLbl.setText("Location: " + this.location);
            this.locationLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 35));
            this.leftPanel.add(this.invNoLbl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            this.leftPanel.add(this.consigneeLbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            this.leftPanel.add(this.locationLbl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            // add all the components to the frame
            this.add(this.numPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
            this.add(this.leftPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] array1 = {"6", "444555", "Ali Murtaza Sumer", "Carson, Ca 90746"};
        String[] array2 = {"7", "444666", "Hasan Huseyin Karabiber", "Los Angeles, Ca 90746"};
        String[] array3 = {"8", "444777", "Mustafa Tinaztepe", "Macomb, IL 61455"};
        String[] array4 = {"9", "444888", "Berkay Surmeli", "Chicago, IL 60625"};
        String[] array5 = {"6", "444555", "Ali Murtaza Sumer", "Carson, Ca 90746"};
        String[] array6 = {"7", "444666", "Hasan Huseyin Karabiber", "Los Angeles, Ca 90746"};
        String[] array7 = {"8", "444777", "Mustafa Tinaztepe", "Macomb, IL 61455"};
        String[] array8 = {"9", "444888", "Berkay Surmeli", "Chicago, IL 60625"};
        ArrayList<String[]> aL = new ArrayList<>();
        aL.add(array1);
        aL.add(array2);
        aL.add(array3);
        aL.add(array4);
        PAndDeliveryNotification question = new PAndDeliveryNotification(aL, "SAVE");
        question.setDelivStopNo();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your [mcve].

Comment: Please read the [mcve] link to know exactly what it is we're asking for and why. Also you should avoid setting component sizes or bounds. Instead call `pack()` on your dialog, call the method noted above per @LuxxMiner, and your dialog should be sized correctly and centered.

Comment: I am actually trying to center the window relative to width, not to height. So, that does not really work for me @LuxxMiner

Comment: When do you set the values of the Dialog? Maybe there is an repaint() problem. Try to set the values before showing the Dialog.

Comment: Well.. I originally posted the whole method but @HovercraftFullOfEels got angry and dared to teach me how to ask questions although it was obviously minimal, complete, and verifiable. Let me post the method. Just letting you know setting values and paintings are in correct order.

Comment: Got angry? Interesting interpretation of a simple one line request. But seriously, read the link to see what we need -- a small program that we can actually compile and run, and that reproduces your problem. Post this and we'll understand your problem quickly, and thus we can likely offer you quick effective help. And no your code was not "complete". I can't paste it into my IDE and compile or run it, can I? And I'm not trying to "teach" you anything. i'm just like everyone else -- I'm trying to better understand your problem, that's all.

Comment: Note that @Kami's question relates to exactly what I'm requesting. But if you'd like to ignore our requests and instead assume that we're miffed or angry, so be it.

Comment: Alright, I understand my question was not complete. Honestly, I thought you were talking about that I should use minimal code and be to the point. That's why I removed the method and left the problematic line of code. I apologize for that. Now, I think my question is complete and it should work if you copy and paste it into your IDE. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: When I ran your code, the dialog was shown without any problems until i removed the `this.setModal(true)`.  May be the problem is because of your MainFrame. Have you tried it without setting  `this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);` i think this call causes the problem.

Comment: Your posted code is almost but not quite an MCVE. I've edited your post to show you a true MCVE, one that has a main method and runs and that displays the dialog on command. The only failing of my changes is that my code does not reproduce your problem. I invite you to change/edit my MCVE so that it reproduces your problem for you.

Comment: and 1+ up-vote for your efforts -- thanks.

Comment: Instead of creating another frame in the main method. I used `new UKDialog("You did something bad", "OK")` and yes, you're right, it works just fine. But, when I create an instance of this from another class, it gives me the problem. I posted that too.

Comment: Post an MCVE with all the necessary code please. That's the purpose of the MCVE. It can have more than one class, but only one public class, the one with the main method, so that the complete code can be pasted into a single IDE file and run.

Comment: I did update my question and added all necessary classes

Comment: You using two JDialog exending Classes. Both of them has `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` and `setModal(true)` therefore both are competing for the view. Maybe you should use a JFrame and JDialog .

Comment: Exatcly!!! That's the problem! Thanks a lot @Kami. Update your answer so I can select it as the correct one. Thanks again!!

Comment: Done :) you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

You using two JDialog exending Classes. Both of them has setAlwaysOnTop(true) and setModal(true) therefore both are competing for the view. Maybe you should use a JFrame and JDialog

Comment: A call to `repaint()` should never be required in this situation after calling `setVisible(true)`. What do you base this recommendation on??

Comment: I thought that same, but the problem was solved when I added the repaint() call. I still thinks the Class which calls the Dialog is competing  with the Dialog, so that after the `setVisible()` was done the MainFrame receives the view immediately  so that the dialog was not able to finish its drawing. But because of the `setAlwaysOnTop()` it lies in front of the MainFrame. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Exactly! I was using `this.setAlwaysOnTop(true)` for two JDialogs on top of each other causing the second one not to load panel components. I simply deleted the setAlwaysOnTop lines from both and it works just fine. `this.setModal(true)` does what I need anyways. Thanks a lot!